# How do you say "proud of you" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

As in if a child does something good, their parents might say "I'm so proud of you" or "Mum is so proud of you".

The only word in the dictionary I seem to be able to find for pride seems to be about self-pride （eg. 自豪).

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/zh-CN/mum%20is%20so%20proud%20of%20you) translate pride as 骄傲 but I always thought that 骄傲 kind of had negative connotations like of someone being a bit arrogant or vain.

Comment: to avoid using 骄傲 could try 对……感觉光荣

Comment: Good question, and to be honest I don't know the word either. What comes to my mind is “妈妈觉得你很棒!” which is a way to express a similar feeling.

Comment: 我为你感到骄傲 is a common sentence。骄傲 do means proud in specified context。

Answer (score 4):

骄傲 is completely correct, you can use 骄傲 in this situation, it won't bring any negative connotations.

In some situations, 骄傲 really means arrogant, for example, "This guy is so 骄傲", "这个人很骄傲".

Below statements fulfill "Mum is so proud of you":

> 妈妈为你感到骄傲
>
> 妈妈为你感到自豪
>
> 妈妈为你感到光荣

To be more emphasize, you could use "无比"，it is like incomparable, for example:

> 妈妈为你感到无比骄傲
>
> 妈妈为你感到无比自豪
>
> 妈妈为你感到光荣无比

Comment: Only in Mainland China 驕傲 has no negative connotation.  It might be influence of Western languages. Russian? English? Traditionally 驕傲 is negative.

Comment: "詞彙鈍化" .... dumbing down .... a common symptom of Westernised Chinese language (歐化中文). e.g.  「及」、「與」、「和」、「同」、「跟」、
「且」、「並」、「而」、「還有」、「以及」、「而且」 => 「和」 ; 「只好」、「情願」、「寧願」、「甘心」、「故意」、「被迫」、「只能」、「只有」、「惟有」 => 「選擇」 ;

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to say that.

```
以你為榮
引以為榮
引以自豪
與有榮焉
光宗耀祖
吐氣揚眉
光耀門楣
家山有福
```

These above-mentioned words illustrate the idea of pride but each has its own idiomatic usage.

For example,

```
媽媽以你為榮。
有子如此，為母引以自豪。
```

Answer (score 0):

"Mum is so proud of you".
媽媽 (Mum) 真是 (is so) 以你為榮 (proud of you)。
媽媽真是以你為榮。

Answer (score 0):

"I'm so proud of you" In this sentence, "proud" being translated to 自豪 is absolutely right, and 骄傲 is also OK. 
In most situation 骄傲 expresses negative connotations, such as "He is very 骄傲", which means he is over proud of himself(自己骄傲). Here subject and object are the same person.
While "sb is proud of him（别人为他感到骄傲）" can express positive meaning. Subject and object are different person.